# Flutter DateFormat Invalid date format

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, datetime-format

I have a string like this `String dt = '04-09-2021 - 15:00'`

i want to convert it into local time zone
and my code is:

```
if(dt != 'Not Available'){
      return DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy - HH:mm')
          .format(DateTime.parse(dt).toLocal())
          .toString();
    }else{
      return dt;
    }
```

But i get the error: `Invalid date format 04-09-2021 - 15:00`

Answer (score 3):

You should use parse, not format, the format functions receive a date, but you don't have a date, you have an string, use:

```dart
DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy - HH:mm').parse(dt);
```

Comment: it's not parsed to local time

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote a dateformatter and convert it to local time. As well as you can format like as you wish.

```
// call getFormattedDateFromFormattedString function in Text
       Center(
                child: Text(getFormattedDateFromFormattedString(
                    currentFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy - HH:mm",
                    desiredFormat: "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a",
                    value: "04-09-2000 - 15:00")),
              )

// date fomatter function
String getFormattedDateFromFormattedString(
    {@required String currentFormat,
    @required String desiredFormat,
    String value}) {
  String formattedDate = "";
  if (value != null || value.isNotEmpty) {
    try {
      DateTime dateTime = DateFormat(currentFormat).parse(value, true).toLocal();
      formattedDate = DateFormat(desiredFormat).format(dateTime);
    } catch (e) {
      print("$e");
    }
  }
  // print("Formatted date time:  $formattedDate");
  return formattedDate.toString();
}
```

Output:

[image]

N.B: My time zone GMT+6.0